# How to combine 2 zip files in Google Cloud Storage

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, google-cloud-storage

Is it possible to combine 2 zip files in Google Cloud Storage? I can successfully combine non-zip files, but when I want to combine zip files, even though the files are successfully combined on the cloud side, I get an error that the folder could not be compressed correctly when I want to download and open it. What is my problem, what am I doing wrong? Can you help me? Thanks..

Example code is blow:

"SharpZipLib" Version="1.4.2"

"Google.Cloud.Storage.V1" Version="4.7.0"

```cs
        // total 10 files in this directory
        string filePath = "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\ziptest"; 
        
        // chunked 5 files in each list
        IEnumerable<string[]> chunkedFilesNames = Directory.GetFiles(filePath).ToList().Chunk(5);
        
        // uploaded files list
        List<string> uploadedFiles = new List<string>(); 
        int i = 0;
        
        // chunked files list
        foreach (string[] fileNames in chunkedFilesNames) 
        {
            using (MemoryStream outputMemStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (ZipOutputStream zipStream = new ZipOutputStream(outputMemStream))
                {
                    // each file in chunked files list
                    foreach (string fileName in fileNames) 
                    {
                        ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(fileName)
                        {
                            DateTime = DateTime.Now
                        };

                        // put next entry to zip stream
                        await zipStream.PutNextEntryAsync(zipEntry); 

                        // read file bytes
                        byte[] bytes = await System.IO.File.ReadAllBytesAsync(fileName); 

                        using (MemoryStream inStream = new MemoryStream(bytes)) 
                        {
                            StreamUtils.Copy(inStream, zipStream, new byte[4096]);
                        }

                        // close entry
                        zipStream.CloseEntry(); 
                    }

                    // chunked zip file name example: test/0_0014b86930954475bb80c79094f690cf.zip
                    string chunkedZip = $"test/{i}_"+Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N")+".zip";
                    
                    // add uploaded file to list
                    uploadedFiles.Add(chunkedZip);
                    
                    zipStream.IsStreamOwner = false;
                    zipStream.Close();
                    
                    // upload zip file to cloud storage
                    await _cloudStorage.UploadMemoryStream(fileName: chunkedZip, contentType: "multipart/x-zip",  stream: outputMemStream);  
                    
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }

        // compose uploaded files
        await _cloudStorage.ComposeObjects(fileNames: uploadedFiles, uploadPath: "test/composed.zip", contentType: "multipart/x-zip");
```

Answer (score 1):

As @John Hanley said, below Data in zip archives is organized.  It is not possible to combine two zip archive files. The directory can be moved and resized, and you can read from one and append to the other. It means that you have to download, handle locally, and then upload again.

As another workaround, In order to get the desired result, you should think about changing the extension from `.zip` to `.tar.gz`; this will enable Compose to operate as intended. As file formats `.gz` and `.tar.gz`, accept concatenation.

Comment: Zip archives are structured data. There is a directory at the end of the object. You cannot concatenate two zip archive files. You can read from one and append to the other, which is moving and resizing the directory. That means you must download, process locally, and re-upload.

Comment: Thank you @John Hanley, for giving more insights. For sake of community i have updated answer.